# Docker machine installation for windows

Tags: docker

I just installed docker-machine for windows using the following command:
[image]

It created a bin folder with a docker-machine.exe file.
However after checking if it installed correctly with **docker-machine version**. I get the following error:
*/c/Users/samta/bin/docker-machine: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'*

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it I download the docker-machine.exe file for windows from github: https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/
and replaced the generated file from the command above.